# How to give specific location to voice recorder

Tags: android

Thanks for previous replies

I am doing application with android inbuilt voice recorder. i want to store the voice in specific location. but whenever i use the android in built voice recorder(using intent action) it save all voice into default folder. is there anyway to customize the location to save the voice. If anyone have idea pls guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from com.android.soundrecorder.Recorder.java,we could find：

```
 public void startRecording(int outputfileformat, String extension) {
    if (mSampleFile == null) {
        File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (!sampleDir.canWrite()) // Workaround for broken sdcard support on the device.
        sampleDir = new File("/sdcard/sdcard");
        try {
            mSampleFile = File.createTempFile(SAMPLE_PREFIX, extension, sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            setError(SDCARD_ACCESS_ERROR);
            return;
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

mSampleFile is created in code, 
So...we can't customize the location to save the voice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator +   "DemoApplication"+File.separator+"Media"+File.separator+"audio"+File.separator);
        if(root.exists())
            root.delete();
        root.mkdirs();
    File voiceDirectory = new File(root, String.format("AudioFile_%d.amr",         System.currentTimeMillis()));

        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(voiceDirectory);

        intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

Comment: Last lacking line of code :                 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);